# How to use an ID on a submit tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wanting to add an ID to a submit tag, (hopefully a class as well to make the submit_tag look like a button but i'll get onto that later)

Heres my code

`<%= submit_tag("Submit ID", :id=>"content") %>`

For some reason the button has completely disappeared.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: You can pass the ID using a `hidden_field`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hey try this way:**

```
 <%= submit_tag "Submit ID", :class => "btn btn-primary", :id => "abcd" %>
```